# joblib parallel processing breaks when running with unordered list in for loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to run my time intensive analysis using joblib parallel, using the same Class_A.func but for 3 different dataframes A_df, B_df and C_df

```
    res_a = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend='loky', verbose=5)(delayed(Class_A.func)(A_df[i]) for i in a.unit.unique().tolist()) 
    res_b = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend='loky', verbose=5)(delayed(Class_A.func)(B_df[i]) for i in b.unit.unique().tolist()) 
    res_c = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend='loky', verbose=5)(delayed(Class_A.func)(C_df[i]) for i in c.unit.unique().tolist())
```

with unique parameters:

```
a.unit.unique().tolist() = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
b.unit.unique().tolist() = [7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 22, 23, 0, 16]
c.unit.unique().tolist() = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 19, 20, 21]
```

The code runs fine with joblib parallel when all 3 unique parameter are the same. example:

```
a.unit.unique().tolist() = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
b.unit.unique().tolist() = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
c.unit.unique().tolist() = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

If they are different, like how I want them to be (shown in the beginning), only the 1st one res_A runs. As soon as the res_a is finished, joblib paralell initiates and gives me the following error:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 16 concurrent workers.
res_b = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, backend='loky', verbose=5)(delayed(Class_A.func)(B_df[i]) for i in b.unit.unique().tolist())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is this because the 1st list is ordered and sequential and the other two are not and this is important when running joblib parallel? or am I missing very trivial?

I can retrieve res_a properly even if it breaks at the beginning of res_b

Thanks for the help!

Comment: All list are ordered. Do you mean *sorted*?

Comment: In any case, you really must provide a [mcve]. I *supect* the error is coming from `B_df[i]) for i in b.unit.unique().tolist()` when you index `B_df[i]`, but you haven't told us what `B_df` is, nor have you provided a full error message and stack trace, nor any simple debugging steps to try to figure out what is causing the error. Please see [ask] and the [help]